# What does 名詞修飾型 mean?

Tags: grammar

In my grammar book, it says 名詞修飾型 + ばかりに、

So what does this mean ? I can find nothing but Chinese web pages about that term.

Answer (score 1):

Edit (see discussion in comments).

It means that the preceding word has to be in attributive form that is:

- 名詞+の/である/だった
- な-adj + な/である/だった
- い-adj (can be conjugated)
- verb (can be conjugated (plain form))

Comment: The preceding word can be the attributive form of an i-adjective or a verb, too.

Comment: It might not be clear but that is what I meant by note that ばかりに can also be preceded by verbs and i adjectives.

Comment: Oh sorry, I've missed the last line. But do you mean 美しい and 行く are not 名詞修飾型?

Comment: @naruto I am not myself familiar with the term 名詞修飾型, but since I understood it as 名詞の修飾型, I would have tend to say that 行く and 美しい are not 名詞修飾型 because they are not nouns.

Comment: 名詞修飾 means "noun-modifying", not "modifying noun". I believe here it's synonymous with "attributive".